# Update XML Parent Element Attribute Using XSLT

Tags: xslt

I hope someone can help, I can't figure this out, maybe it just can't be done.

I have the following XML and need to update RedressNumber and KnownTravelerNumber based on a condition of Document elements.  I am using the following XSLT but it's not working.

The attribute should be copied as is if DocTypeCode condition is not true.
The attribute value should be replaced with DocID value if condition is true.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:import href="identity.xsl" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="ProfileRead">
        <xsl:apply-imports />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ProfileRead/Profile/Traveler/Customer">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:for-each select="Document">
                <xsl:if test="@DocTypeCode = 'KTID'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="KnownTravelerNumber">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@DocID"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="@DocTypeCode = 'RDNR'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="RedressNumber">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@DocID"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>       
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ProfileRead/Profile/Traveler/Customer/@KnownTravelerNumber" />
    <xsl:template match="ProfileRead/Profile/Traveler/Customer/@RedressNumber" />

    <!-- remove element -->
    <xsl:template match="ProfileRead/Profile/Traveler/Customer/Document[@DocTypeCode='KTID']" />
    <xsl:template match="ProfileRead/Profile/Traveler/Customer/Document[@DocTypeCode='RDNR']" />

</xsl:stylesheet>

<ProfileRead>
    <Profile>
        <Traveler>
            <Customer GenderCode="M" RedressNumber="321" KnownTravelerNumber="123">
                <PersonName LanguageIDCode="EN-US">
                    <GivenName>John</GivenName>
                    <MiddleName>Long</MiddleName>
                    <SurName>Smith</SurName>
                    <NameSuffix>Junior</NameSuffix>
                </PersonName>
                <Document DocID="666" DocTypeCode="RDNR" />
                <Document DocID="111" DocTypeCode="KAMAL" />
                <Document DocID="222" DocTypeCode="FRANK" />
            </Customer>
        </Traveler>
    </Profile>
</ProfileRead>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't show exactly what you want for your result, but I'm keying on the phrase "copied as is" ... I think all you have to do is copy your attributes before processing your attributes.  In XSLT you are allowed to add an attribute node multiple times to the output element and the last one wins ... earlier ones added are simply overwritten.

So in the text below all I did was copy the attributes first, then process them, and I took out your template matches that removed the attributes.

```
t:\ftemp>type profile.xml 
<ProfileRead>
    <Profile>
        <Traveler>
            <Customer GenderCode="M" RedressNumber="321" KnownTravelerNumber="123">
                <PersonName LanguageIDCode="EN-US">
                    <GivenName>John</GivenName>
                    <MiddleName>Long</MiddleName>
                    <SurName>Smith</SurName>
                    <NameSuffix>Junior</NameSuffix>
                </PersonName>
                <Document DocID="666" DocTypeCode="RDNR" />
                <Document DocID="111" DocTypeCode="KAMAL" />
                <Document DocID="222" DocTypeCode="FRANK" />
            </Customer>
        </Traveler>
    </Profile>
</ProfileRead>
t:\ftemp>call xslt2 profile.xml profile.xsl 
<ProfileRead>
    <Profile>
        <Traveler>
            <Customer GenderCode="M" RedressNumber="666" KnownTravelerNumber="123">
                <PersonName LanguageIDCode="EN-US">
                    <GivenName>John</GivenName>
                    <MiddleName>Long</MiddleName>
                    <SurName>Smith</SurName>
                    <NameSuffix>Junior</NameSuffix>
                </PersonName>

                <Document DocID="111" DocTypeCode="KAMAL"/>
                <Document DocID="222" DocTypeCode="FRANK"/>
            </Customer>
        </Traveler>
    </Profile>
</ProfileRead>

t:\ftemp>type profile.xsl 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:import href="identity.xsl" />
    <xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8" />
    <xsl:template match="ProfileRead">
        <xsl:apply-imports />
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="ProfileRead/Profile/Traveler/Customer">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*"/>       
            <xsl:for-each select="Document">
                <xsl:if test="@DocTypeCode = 'KTID'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="KnownTravelerNumber">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@DocID"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
                <xsl:if test="@DocTypeCode = 'RDNR'">
                    <xsl:attribute name="RedressNumber">
                        <xsl:value-of select="@DocID"/>
                    </xsl:attribute>
                </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()"/>       
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- remove element -->
    <xsl:template match="ProfileRead/Profile/Traveler/Customer/Document[@DocTypeCode='KTID']" />
    <xsl:template match="ProfileRead/Profile/Traveler/Customer/Document[@DocTypeCode='RDNR']" />

</xsl:stylesheet>
t:\ftemp>rem Done!
```

Comment: This exactly what I needed accomplish.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: Then I will thank you to please do me the courtesy of accepting the answer.